# PySimpleGUI get selected extension from FileSaveAs dialog box

Tags: python, tkinter, pysimplegui

I created a [FileSaveAs](https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#chooser-buttons) button in my PySimpleGUI application, and defined the available `file_types` to be 'png' and 'jpg', but I have no way of knowing which of these two options was selected by the user. In other words, unless explicitly entered by the user, the value I get does not include the file extension.

Here's the code:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [[
    sg.InputText(visible=False, enable_events=True, key='fig_path'),
    sg.FileSaveAs(
        key='fig_save',
        file_types=(('PNG', '.png'), ('JPG', '.jpg')),  # TODO: better names
    )
]]
window = sg.Window('Demo Application', layout, finalize=True)

fig_canvas_agg = None
while True:  # Event Loop
    event, values = window.Read()
    if (event == 'fig_path') and (values['fig_path'] != ''):
        print('Saving to:', values['fig_path'])
    if event is None:
        break
```

Example:

[image]

In the above case, the value will be "[some path]\Test\hello", instead of ending with "hello.png".

Any way of either getting the returned path to include the extension, or getting the extension value separately?

Comment: Relevant [How to save text from a Text-widget Tkinter to a .doc using asksaveasfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26453933/7414759)

Answer (score 0):

Add `defaultextension="*.*"` to `tk.filedialog.asksaveasfilename ()`

It's around line 3332 in ver 4.30.0 of pysimplegui.py

Comment: Fixed in version 4.30.0.16 on GitHub.